# How to filter nested array in python pymongo 3.7.2 for mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo version 3.7.2 with python 3.6.8. I have documents in the following format in my database:

```
{"_id" : 1,
"main_array":[
{"subid":222,
"subarray":[{"name":"hari","status":1},{"name":"henry","status":1}]
},
{"subid":333,
"subarray":[{"name":"james","status":0},{"name":"jason","status":1}]
}]
},
{"_id" : 2,
"main_array":[
{"subid":222,
"subarray":[{"name":"alex","status":1},{"name":"anna","status":1}]
},
{"subid":333,
"subarray":[{"name":"bob","status":0},{"name":"bunny","status":1}]
}]
}
```

I need to get the objects with subid = 222 from all the documents in the collection. The required result should be as follows:

```
{"_id" : 1,
"main_array":[
{"subid":222,
"subarray":[{"name":"hari","status":1},{"name":"henry","status":1}]
}]
},
{"_id" : 2,
"main_array":[
{"subid":222,
"subarray":[{"name":"alex","status":1},{"name":"anna","status":1}]
}]

}
```

I tried the following code:

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(<mongoclient url>)
mydb = myclient["test"]
mycol = mydb["user"]  
subid = 222
_id = 1
x = mycol.find({"_id":_id},{"main_array":{"$elemMatch":{"subid":subid}}})
```

I got the required result for a particular document. But i need for all the documents. I tried the following query:

```
x = mycol.find({"main_array":{"$elemMatch":{"subid":subid}}})
```

But this time it returns the entire collection. What did i miss ?

Answer (score 0):

`elemMatch` gives you the documents in which ANY of the array item passes the condition.

You should use the aggregation pipeline with `$unwind` and `$match`.

Basically, do:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $unwind: "$main_array"
},
{
  $match: {
    "main_array.subid": 222
  }
}])
```

This gives `main_array` as an object though, but you should be able to work with that.

Output of the above:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "main_array": {
      "subarray": [
        {
          "name": "hari",
          "status": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "henry",
          "status": 1
        }
      ],
      "subid": 222
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "main_array": {
      "subarray": [
        {
          "name": "alex",
          "status": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "anna",
          "status": 1
        }
      ],
      "subid": 222
    }
  }
]
```

Fiddle: https://mongoplayground.net/p/-sg_d2h5wIJ

Comment: It worked. I had to use the pipeline like this:`[{ "$unwind": "$main_array" }, { "$match": { "main_array.subid": 222 } } ]` . **Include it in square brackets**